# Window screenshot through Javascript or PHP or is there any reliable API to get this

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

Is there any possibility to take screenshot through javascript of window or div elements. I used "HTML5's CANVAS" but the result is not so fine. Or is there any reliable API to get this?

Comment: What do you mean "the result is not so fine"? Thanks.

Comment: cannot be done with PHP as PHP is server-side, and is completely unaware of what is happening on clients screen..

Comment: whole operation can not be done by php or you can export an HTML5 canvas as PNG image (making a screenshot) and then send the PNG to a PHP script using JQUERY , finaly save the PNG on the webserver.

Comment: If Browsers enable web devs to do this, then I don't think I want to use one anymore... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser.

See Examples at http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

Or You can use [EaselJS](http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/10/export-and-save-a-screenshot-of-an-html5-canvas-using-php-jquery-and-easeljs/)

Export and save a screenshot of an HTML5 Canvas
using PHP, JQuery and EaselJS

EaselJS steps:

- export an HTML5 canvas as PNG image (making a screenshot)
- send the PNG to a PHP script using jQuery
- save the PNG on the webserver
- setup an EaselJS project

Answer (score 0):

Use Phantomjs to get the screenshot of the window. its headlessbrowser or else what you need can you explain